# GTM and GA4: Access gtm.element.value not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a project that uses GTM and GA4. In GTM I have an event (connected with GA), that needs to track user input (search bar).

The trigger seems to work right - it fires when required. When I look at the dataLayer from the click event (after search input was typed in), I can see that the value of the search bar can be found under: gtm.click.value.

That's why I've created a custom variable. But for some reason the custom variable always returns "" (empty string). I don't understand why, because when I check the dataLayer in my console, I see the right value. I've double-checked, if I'm tracking the right click event - and I do: the gtm.uniqueEventId is the right one.

Can someone tell me what's wrong? How can I access the gtm.element.value?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a Custom JS varialbe and have this in it:

```js
funciton(){
  return {{Click Element}}.value;
}
```

See if it returns the value of your clicked element.